# python beginner problem with type casting

Tags: python

I am a beginner with python.I want to do the function over each member of the user imputed list,yet the most common error is '

> could not convert string to float

This the code

> ```
> import math            
> l=[]  
> i=0  
> while True:
>     t=str(input('Enter the probability of possibl outcomes: '))
>
>     if (t!='stop') and (t!=''):
>         l.append(t.lower())
>     else:
>         print(l)
>         break
> def I(i):
>     i=l[0]
>     z=1/(i)
>     y=math.log(z,2)
>     I(i)
> ```

this program is supposed to take few inputs and make a list, and the apply the function to all the element in the list, however I keep getting the above mentioned error and I don't know how to remove it. please help.

Comment: your code is full of bugs.

Comment: Make sure your indentations are correct in your example code aswell.

Comment: Not a proper question, please make sure your indentation is correct

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
i=l[0]
```

to

```
try:
   i=float(l[0])
except:
   ...
```

This wont work in your case :

```
t=float(input('Enter the probability of possible outcomes: '))
```

as the string can be "Stop" as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
t=str(input('Enter the probability of possibl outcomes: '))
```

should be changed to

```
t=float(input('Enter the probability of possibl outcomes: '))
```

This way it converts user input(which is a string, since input() always returns a string) to a floating-point number
However this way you will be able to use only numbers as your input value, and your while loop will be infinite. If you would try to enter "stop" it will give you an error. Code should be changed to something like this:

```
import math            
l=[]  
i=0  

while True:
    t = input('Enter the probability of possibl outcomes: ')

    if (t!='stop') and (t!=''):
        l.append(float(t))
    else:
        print(l)
        break 

def I(i):
    i=l[0]
    z=1/(i)
    y=math.log(z,2)

I(i)
```

Output:

```
Enter the probability of possibl outcomes: 45
Enter the probability of possibl outcomes: 36
Enter the probability of possibl outcomes: 11
Enter the probability of possibl outcomes: stop
[45.0, 36.0, 11.0]
```

Comment: You should at least add a `try/except`. Not everything can be casted to a float

Comment: t=float(input('Enter the probability of possibl outcomes: '))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1/2'

Comment: @Evilunclebill True, I've taken a closer look and fixed my answer. However, since the author is a complete beginner I don't want to overburden him with try clauses and other stuff and keep everything as close to the original code as I can. Also, I don't want to fix every single mistake(and there are a lot of them). This way the author can test the code and figure out how to improve it by himself.

Comment: With this method, is there a way to use fractions as an input?ValueError: could not convert string to float

Comment: @Димчик of course. just give a number as an input, not an operation. Meaning you should input 0.5 instead of 1/2

Answer (score 0):

You could change this line - `l.append(t.lower())` to `l.append(float(t.lower()))`